# Ubuntu not installing on Lenovo ThinkPad E460

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, lenovo, thinkpad

I have been trying to install Ubuntu (and other *buntus) on our new E460, but after installation, it attempts to boot to PXE (network boot), then only shows the hard drive on a boot management screen, but fails to recognize OS.

I can boot to USB install disk.

I created /, /home, /boot, and "region for bios" within installation.  Every attempt of install, all mount points were recreated.

I have spent past 2 days searching and trying various suggestions but now feel like hitting a brick wall. Somehow during these steps, the original OS (Win 7/Win 10) has stopped responding to the recovery disk ... but that is another problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Additional:
I used the "[installation of Ubuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1)" and received the following errors:

```
cp: cannot stat '/target/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{efi}/ubuntu/shim*.efi': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/target/boot/efi/EFI/boot/shim.efi': No such file or directory
```

I ran the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and received the following results:
[Pasted Results.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24389473/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: I went through all the steps ... first time seeing the code for UEFI toward the end.
After running the script, I get
"cp: cannot stat '/target/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{efi}/ubuntu/shim*.efi': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/target/boot/efi/EFI/boot/shim.efi': No such file or directory"

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Thanks Rod ... here are results - http://paste.ubuntu.com/24389473/